# How to persist a collection of forms embedded in a collection of Forms...?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

For my Poll Application i created a FormType called CampaignType which holds a CollectionType named blocks which in turn holds a CollectionType named lines, which holds a CollectionType named fields, which holds a CollectionType named pollResults.

In my next code example you can see my code that renders the View to fill a campaign(poll).

```
public function fillAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $campaign = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Campaign::class)->find($id);
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    foreach ($campaign->getBlocks() AS $block){
        foreach ($block->getLines() AS $line){
            foreach ($line->getFields() AS $field){

                $pollResult = new PollResult();
                $pollResult->setCampaign($campaign);
                $pollResult->setField($field);
                $pollResult->setUser($this->getUser());

                $entityManager->persist($pollResult);

                $field->getPollResults()->add($pollResult);
            }
        }
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(CampaignType::class, $campaign);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        var_dump("true");
        //$entityManager->persist($campaign);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute("grappt_poll_campaignShow", ['id' => $id]);
    }

    return $this->render('GrapptPollBundle:Campaigns:fill.html.twig', [
        'campaign' => $campaign,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

The only thing that must be persisted in the database are the PollResults.
Every PollResult has an entry for the `campaign_id` and the `field_id` it belongs to, the `user_id` who filled out the campaign and the `value` the user chose (and of course its own `id`, which gets generated automatically).

My Problem is that i don't know how to do that.
Where do i have to call `$entityManager->persist($pollResult);`.
Right now i put it directly under the initialization-stuff.
Do i have to put it into the `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())`-query and loop through every pollResult?
Do i have to call `$entityManager->persist($campaign);` although nothing changes there?
Furthermore i wonder if i have to add something for the value-entry of each PollResult?

Thanks in advance for every answer

lxg

Answer (score 1):

#### What will `$form->isValid()` return ?

It will depend on the validation constraints of you master form. If your validation constraints are in the annotations of your entity, in your master entity you should have the `@Assert\Valid()` annotation which will be sure that the nested form is valid :

```
class Campaign
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(…)
     * @Assert\Valid() // <- this line here
     */
    private $blocks;
    ...
```

If you prefer to put your validation constraints in your CampaignType, you can put it in the options :

```
public function buildForm (FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('blocks', CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type' => BlockType::class,
            'constraints' => array(new Valid()) // <- this line here
            ...
```

#### So, where should you put the `persist()`?

The best is to have Symfony's form validation (`->isValid()`) before any persistance, for security and data sanity (don't persist before ensuring csrf protection for instance). If you may add a lot of data (like persisting thousands of entities after one form submission), you can look into Doctrine's batch processing and bulk inserts : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/batch-processing.html

#### Should you also persist the `Campaign` object ?

It depends on the cascade persistence rules you have in your entity.
You can find all the rules to fine-tune the cascade here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations